# can't download file with scp- no error but the file don't download

Tags: scp

I'm trying to download a file using scp

I run

```
scp user@ip:/home/user/file.gzip $HOME/Desktop
```

I get

```
file.gzip                                 100%  156MB 155.8MB/s   00:01
```

but the file is not found

I tried on Ubuntu and Windows and the results is the same. And I tried with another destiny folder, but the file don't found.
Please I appreciate any help

Comment: what is `$HOME`? What is `ls -l $HOME/Desktop/`?

Answer (score 0):

Using that syntax, scp will attempt to save the file with the name 'Desktop'

Instead, save it inside your home folder by specifying a filename explicitly:

```
scp user@ip:/home/user/file.gzip $HOME/file.gzip
```

Or, to preserve the original filename and save inside your 'Desktop' folder, append forward slash period:

```
scp user@ip:/home/user/file.gzip $HOME/Desktop/.
```